# PHP is occasionally saturating my production web server CPU for 10 minutes - How can I examine the cause when the server is in this state?

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, xhprof

My Apache PHP servers sometimes appear to become CPU bound for around 10 minutes and then go back to being normal. I've looked at these hosts in perf (system profiler) and it's all in PHP (5.6.11).

We need to be able to profile the actual PHP code when this happens to see what is going on. Optimally we would be able to have a profiler installed at all times, and enable it when we catch a box in this condition.

What is a good strategy for examining a CPU saturated PHP web server in production to understand what's going on?

Comment: What OS on these servers?

Comment: Have you looked into dtrace(1)/dtruss(1)?

Comment: NewRelic is definably great, but you got to pay... It will tell you what processes are eating up your CPU and also what transactions in you application are taking a long time